# How to remove project's root dir from include path in qmake

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, std, qmake

The default behavior for qmake is to add project's root path to include path. In Makefile it generates something like:

```
INCPATH       = -I..\bug -I. -I..\..\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++
```

where "bug" is the name of the project. I don't want "-I." part. How can I remove this in `.pro` file?

I tried:

```
INCLUDEPATH -= "."
```

but it changes nothing.

**Detailed explanation**: My project compiles fine on Linux, but on Windows (mingw) it fails to compile. After deep research I realized that there is file named "process.h" somewhere included in standard C++ library (string.h). The problem was that in my project there was a file with exactly the same name. And 
paradoxically the file from my project was included to the standard library's header(!!). That behavior causes string header file fail to compile.

Comment: An obvious solution is to just rename the `process.h` file in your project.

Comment: @KubaOber It is not any solution. It is a workaround.

Comment: That's disputable. You will keep running into that problem repeatedly on other build systems as well. Generally speaking, it's a very bad idea to have any files in your project that are named the same as any of the popular standard headers. By concentrating on qmake you're kicking the can down the road :)

Comment: The problem could be more generic. Personally, I don't need project's root path in my INCLUDEPATH as I always use `#include "foo.h"` instead of `#include <foo.h>` because that's the main reason for separated syntax was invented long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's appriopriate config option:

```
CONFIG += no_include_pwd
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for researching and filing a "non-documented" QTBUG. It actually works, but I'm confused what is going on in my project. When the project is called "bug" I had originally this INCPATH: -I../bug -I../bug/src -I../bug -I. After adding you CONFIG line I get this: -I../bug/src -I../bug Any Idea why I originally had multiple "-I../bug" paths in it? And why is it still there (a single time) after adding the CONFIG option? I might be wrong but "-I../bug" is the same as "-I.", isn't it?

Comment: @FrozenTarzan I don't see your *.pro file - all the answers should be inside. Consider asking new question :)

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to know if you also still had the "back one directory and forward into project dir" include path after the changes. I'm just wondering about the "-I../project_dir" path which seems to come from some command. If you tell me that you did not have any of those after the change and got rid of the "-I." and "-I../bug" then I open a new question :-)

Comment: @FrozenTarzan I didn't have the same paths two times AND my bug was fixed by this commit so I can assume I haven't had such problem. But I can't check it now. I also didn't check it on Linux as there was no problem even without this config set (I think you are at Linux right now).

Comment: Yes I am. Thanks anyways, now I know that I need to investigate that further :-)